# Set number of compute units (CPU)

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

I'm trying to set the number of compute units in OpenCL program running on CPU (Intel i7-7550u).

I am just asking if there's a similar function as the set_num_threads for OpenMP.

Answer (score 0):

[clCreateSubDevices](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateSubDevices.html) will create a subdevice with the selected amount of cores but I don't think many devices actually support creating subdevices, somebody correct me if I'm wrong.

But limiting amount of compute units is not exactly the same as setting the amount of threads in OpenMP. Limiting the amount of global work items is more equivalent to limiting amount of threads whereas limiting the amount of compute units will limit how many concurrent threads you will be running.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to the set num threads function of OpenMP in OpenCL.
The closest thing you can do is to configure the total number of threads is during kernel dispatch, see [1]

The total number of concurrent threads of execution is the local work group size, whereas the total number of threads that will execute is the global work size.

[1]https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html